# Pandas merge problems

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by

I have two dataframes

```
df1

    KO-ST  1_UID      2_Vloge
0   1976-_  200106897  200106897.0
1    991-_  200108737  200108737.0
2  2147---  200109776  200109776.0
3   2048-_  200300912  200300912.0
4   2194-_  200301057  200301057.0
5  2386---  200301312  200301312.0
6   2002-_  200301315  200301315.0
7   1324-_  200301573  200301573.0
8   1625-45  200301868  200301868.0
9   1625-_  200301868  200301868.0
...

df2
                              a                    b
SID  KO-ST                                     
10000002 851-601          288.0                288.0
10000003 851-1             68.0                 68.0
10000328 853-103           64.5                 64.5
10000583 861-25            30.1                 30.1
10001002 2590-1            96.7                178.9
10001004 2593-2           349.2                349.2
10001005 2593-3           282.0                295.2
10001006 2593-4           121.5                121.5
10001008 2593-6           109.3                110.3
10001009 2593-7             9.9                  9.9
...
```

There is more than 500.000 rows, where `KO-ST` is unique and `SID` can be repeated. I am trying to group them and repeat the values from columns `a` and `b`. Values from KO-ST are unique and in 10 % cases - not perfect and this cases (e.g. 1324-___) there will be no matches in df2.

My initial code is

```
REN_ES = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, on = 'KO-ST')
```

But i get an error:

```
KeyError: 'KO-ST'
```

Where did I get it wrong? df1 is a result from importing 2 csv files and combining and merging some values. For easier data treatment, column `KO-ST` was added as a combination of two columns with function:

```
DS_STA['KO-ST'] =DS_STA['KO_SIFKO'].map(str) + "-" + DS_STA['STEV'].map(str)
```

`KO-SIFKO` and `STEV` are integers, hence the code. I added this beacuse I'm suspecting there's something wrong with the recognition of data types.

Comment: Not about this question but .astype(str) is more efficient than .map(str)

Comment: Tried and... it's the same error @lwileczek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

df2 has a multi index and "KO-ST" is not a column name. `left_index=True` overwrites `on'KO-ST"` so remove that.  try:

```
REN_ES = pd.merge(df1, df2.reset_index(), on = 'KO-ST')
```